# Grouping the array of codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two different types of `codes`.

```
AllCodes = [
  {
    group_name: 'Marked',
    group_codes: [
      {
        code: '1A',
        description: 'Marked.'
      }
    ],
    .. //next group codes.
  }
 ]

AllCodes = [
  {
    code: '2',
    description: 'Located. Facilities Marked.'
  }
  .. //next codes.
]
```

I need to form an array of this format.

```
[
  {
    code: '1A',
    description: 'example'
  },
  .. // next code
]
```

I did it this way, but I do not really like this approach, how can I dry up the code?

```
def up
  Account.all.each do |account|
    arrayed_codes = []
    account.one_call_center.response_codes_repository_class::AllCodes.collect do |codes|
      if response_code[:group_codes]
        response_code[:group_codes].each do |group_codes|
          arrayed_codes << {
            code: group_codes[:code],
            description: group_codes[:description]
          }
        end
      else
        arrayed_codes << {
          code: response_code[:code],
          description: response_code[:description]
        }
      end
    end
    arrayed_codes.each do |res_code|
      ResponseCode.create!(account: account,
                           one_call_center_id: account.one_call_center.id,
                           close_code: res_code[:code],
                           description: res_code[:description],
                           ticket_types: account.one_call_center.ticket_types.keys)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# obj is an each element of your AllCodes array

codes = AllCodes.inject([]) do |codes_array, obj|
  if obj.has_key?(:group_codes)
    codes_array += obj[:group_codes]
  else
    codes_array << obj
  end
end
```

`codes_array` is an injected array. Iterating over your `AllCodes`, if current object `has_key?(:group_codes)`, we should take `obj[:group_codes]` (because it's already an array of needed format), so we merge our `codes_array` with it: `codes_array += obj[:group_codes]`. If it doesn't have that key, than it's already hash of needed format. So we just add this element to the array.